# Check how many of the same chars line op in list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list,

```
l=[0,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
```

for example,
I want to check if the list contain at least 7 `1's` next to each other.

I'm not sure how to check this.

to clarify:

```
a=[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ] #should return True   
b=[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ] #should return False
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use a simple for loop and count ones, reset your counter if you hit a zero and break out of the loop if counter reaches 7

Comment: You should show us what you tried and what your ideas are instead of only asking for a solution. A first step is mostly how you as a human would solve that problem and then translate it into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way is concatenating the list into a string and check if the `1...` are there like this:

```py
l_true = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ] #should return True
l_false = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ] #should return False


check = lambda x: '1'*7 in ''.join(str(num) for num in x)

print(check(l_true))
>>> True
print(check(l_false))
>>> False
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check if any sublist of 7 elements match with a list of 7 of 1:

```
def f(l):
    pat = [1] * 7
    for i in range(len(l)-7):
        if l[i: i+7] == pat: 
            return True

    return False
```

same idea in the following one-line code:

```
[1] * 7 in (l[i:i+7] for i in range(len(l) - 7))
```

Comment: you can have [0, 0 , 0, 0, 0,0 ,7, 0]  and by using `sum` to the first 7 elements your function will give a wring answer

Comment: you are right,unless it is 1s and 0s only it will work,let me see if I can modify it for your case

Comment: I think is better now

Comment: always prefer one line code,even better with lambda

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `itertools.groupby`.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
for i in data:
    if any((k==1 and len(list(v)) >=7) for k, v in groupby(i) ):
        print("Ok", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is simple as that:

```
alist = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

def is_sequence_exist(alist, count, item):
    _count = 0
    for elem in alist:
        if elem == item:
            _count += 1
            if _count == count:
                return True
        else:
            _count = 0

    return False


print(is_sequence_exist(alist, 2, 1))
```